# How to get/request the api: https://ev.io/stats-by-un/(username)

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to show in game stats when the player puts in $stats (username)

```
import Keep_alive
import tkinter as tk
import discord
import os
import asyncio
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
import asyncio
import datetime as dt

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(arg)
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(arg)

@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(
  title="Hello!",
  description="Im a embed text!")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

Keep_alive.Keep_alive()  
bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Alright so first of all, I don't see you using the API in your code. Try it out and if you face errors, we are here to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to request the api which you need the requests module.

```
import requests
```

Next, you need to know how to get the data from the requested api.

```
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx, *, username):
    # This is how you request data from the api
    data = requests.get(f"https://ev.io/stats-by-un/{username}").json()
    # This is how you get certain stats from the data
    # I don't know what does this api request, so I'm just going to use kills as an example.
    # Different apis have different methods to get certain data, so it's better to take a look at their documentation.
    kills = data["kills"]
    await ctx.send(f"{username} has {kills} kills in total.")
```

I wouldn't suggest using requests within asynchronous code since it's blocking. discord.py uses **aiohttp**, so it should already be installed.

Here's an example code using aiohttp and discord.py:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
    async with cs.get(f"https://ev.io/stats-by-un/{username}") as r:
        response = await r.json()
        await ctx.send(f"{username} has {response["kills"]} kills in total.)
```